# Switch off DTD loading and validation in XmlValidatingMessageSelector

Tags: java, spring-integration

How it's possible to prevent DTD loading (and validation) in `XmlValidatingMessageSelector` if `!DOCTYPE` section is present in incoming XML in Spring Integration?

**UPDATE**

Actually, in our SI config we have this filter config

```
@Bean
public MessageSelector cageXmlValidator() {
    XmlValidatingMessageSelector selector = new XmlValidatingMessageSelector(
            new ClassPathResource("/CageMessage.xsd"),
            XmlValidatingMessageSelector.SchemaType.XML_SCHEMA);
    selector.setThrowExceptionOnRejection(true);
    return selector;
}
```

and use it in our flow in the such way

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow processorFlow(
        ...
        MessageSelector cageXmlValidator,
        Unmarshaller cageXmlUnmarshaller,
        ...) {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(cageInputChannel())
            ...
            .filter(cageXmlValidator)
            .transform(new UnmarshallingTransformer(cageXmlUnmarshaller))
            ... 
            .channel(cageOutputChannel())
            .get();
}
```

I tried also this `XmlValidatingMessageSelector` definition but it doesn't work

```
@Bean
public MessageSelector cageXmlValidator() throws Exception {
    XmlValidatingMessageSelector selector = new XmlValidatingMessageSelector(
            new ClassPathResource("/CageMessage.xsd"),
            XmlValidatingMessageSelector.SchemaType.XML_SCHEMA);

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-dtd-grammar", false);
    factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
    selector.setConverter(new DefaultXmlPayloadConverter(factory));

    selector.setThrowExceptionOnRejection(true);
    return selector;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a test-case like:

```
@Test
public void testValidMessage() throws Exception {
    Document doc = XmlTestUtil.getDocumentForString("<!DOCTYPE greeting SYSTEM \"greeting.dtd\"><greeting>hello</greeting>");
    GenericMessage<Document> docMessage = new GenericMessage<Document>(doc);
    PollableChannel validChannel = ac.getBean("validOutputChannel", PollableChannel.class);
    MessageChannel inputChannel = ac.getBean("inputChannelA", MessageChannel.class);
    inputChannel.send(docMessage);
    assertNotNull(validChannel.receive(100));
}
```

Pay attention to the `!DOCTYPE` declaration in the MXL snippet.

That `XmlTestUtil.getDocumentForString()` has this code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
builder.setNamespaceAware(true);
builder.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-dtd-grammar", false);
builder.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);


return builder.newDocumentBuilder().parse(
        new InputSource(new StringReader(strDoc)));
```

The latest `load-external-dtd` feature does exactly what I need.

So, what you need in your application is to consider to build `Document` for your XML in advance before validation and use those feature for the `DocumentBuilderFactory`.

**UPDATE**

The inserting a customized `DefaultXmlPayloadConverter` with an appropriate `DocumentBuilderFactory` doesn't have effect for our payload:

```
validationExceptions = this.xmlValidator.validate(this.converter.convertToSource(message.getPayload()));
```

Where that `convertToSource()` looks like:

```
public Source convertToSource(Object object) {
    Source source = null;
    if (object instanceof Source) {
        source = (Source) object;
    }
    else if (object instanceof Document) {
        source = new DOMSource((Document) object);
    }
    else if (object instanceof String) {
        source = new StringSource((String) object);
    }
    else {
        throw new MessagingException("unsupported payload type [" + object.getClass().getName() + "]");
    }
    return source;
}
```

As you see nobody calls that `DocumentBuilderFactory`.

What I suggest you to have a `.transform()` upfront `.filter(cageXmlValidator)` to transform your `payload` to the `Document` object with the customized `DocumentBuilderFactory`.

Seeing the fact that we can't affect internals of the `javax.xml.validation.Validator`, I think that would be good compromise to call `convertToDocument()` from the validator and wrap it into `DOMSource`. That way, indeed, your `DefaultXmlPayloadConverter` would have an effect.

Feel free to raise a JIRA or even consider contribution.

Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Thank you. Will try... Where is `XmlTestUtil` class?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-xml/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/xml/util/XmlTestUtil.java. But that shouldn't bother you because it doesn't have a code I show you here.

Comment: Provided solution doesn't work. Looks like `setFeature` settings doesn't affect a parser is created inside `XmlValidatingMessageSelector`.

Comment: Of course it doesn't, because that is a part of external `DocumentBuilderFactory` instance and fully unrelated to the `XmlValudator` internals. You should share some code to reproduce from our side and would be better to have some StackTrace on the matter. As much as possible info is really useful. Thanks

Comment: Pls, see update question definition with my SI configuration

Comment: See an UPDATE, please, in my answer.

Comment: Now it works! Are you saying about PR with changes in `XmlValidatingMessageSelector#accept` change? BTW why `XmlPayloadConverter#convertToSource` method needed in API then? No one is used it in SI code. Can we remove it at all then?

Comment: That's different story. Please, JIRA first. And we never remove working public API. It's framework, open source, you can't assume that nobody uses it

Comment: Sure: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/2197